# Decreasing minimum upload time with AWS S3?

Tags: android, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm building an android app that needs to send small files between clients (about 15kb on average). The client are already communicating via websocket. My current solution is to upload the file to S3 and use the websocket to notify everyone that there's a new file to download. I'm uploading the file with [AmazonS3Client.PutObject()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#putObject%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest%29).

However, I noticed a few seconds of delay, that I'd like to avoid. No matter how small the file, it always takes at least 2 seconds to upload. I would like to decrease this time if possible. I'm also open to alternative solutions, but it's important that I can have one-to-many transfer of the files.

Answer (score 1):

This is called latency.  There's two measures of speed in networking-  throughput (the amount of data you can transfer per second) and latency (how long it takes to send any data at all).  Latency is because it takes time to send a message from your phone to the cell tower, from there to the internet, from the internet to AWS, and from AWS to the specific server dealing with your storage.  Its mostly a factor of the networking technology and the physical distance between source and destination.  There's really not much you can do about it.

Comment: 2 seconds seems like a lot of latency to me. I'm sure a large factor of it is due to latency, but I would like to know if there's something else I'm missing. Or at the very least if there's something I can measure so that I'm certain that's the only problem.

Comment: Over cellular?  That sounds pretty standard. 100-1000ms RTT is the norm, cellular data is not fast-  it tends to get bounced to a satellite and the latency of satellites is horrendous.

Comment: Also, don't forget that you aren't doing a simple http call.  You're calling a webservice which will call other wbeservices to actually store the data.  So their processing time won't be 0 either.

Comment: It seems odd to me because the latency I get from my apps to my websocket server is significantly smaller. But as you point out, I don't know what kind of processing AWS does. I guess I'd just like to know if this is the norm.